# Call a python subprocess as daemon and exit

Tags: python, daemon, python-2.x

I'm using a pair of python programs, one of which should call the second.

But this should be done in a way that the first program makes the second one a daemon (or running in the background process), then exits, without waiting for the second program to end.

Is this possible in Python?

I've been looking at os.fork, subprocess module, but I'm quite confused as the correct way to achieve this...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for this:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['/usr/bin/python', '/path/to/my/second/pythonscript.py']
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

You might want to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` somewhere, you can do that by passing `stdout=<file_obj>` to the `Popen` constructor.

Comment: So, according to this, 'daemon_process' should be made equal to something like '/usr/bin/pyton /path/to/my/second/pythonscript.py' ?

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. `Popen` takes a list of arguments. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: May I add to this question (which was quite useful to me) that one can have the realtime output from using `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr`)? Thanks.

Comment: Is this Python 2? I can't get it to work in Python 3.7.8 (and sending stdout/stderr to devnull). And it seems surprisingly hard to daemonize a process, so far.

Answer (score 17):

A "daemon" carries a more specific definition than just "background process". By default `Popen` will execute a subprocess and give control back to your program to continue running. However, that says nothing about dealing with signals (notably, SIGHUP if the user exits their shell before your background process finished) or disconnecting from stdin, stderr, stdout and any other file descriptors opened at the time you invoke `Popen`.
If you truly mean that you want a daemon, you should use the [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) module, an implementation of PEP 3143. This takes care of the gross parts you don't want to think about.