# open independent process python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm running into a problem using the subprocess module to open completely independent processes through Python. I need the process spawned by the python script to live on even if the python program dies. I've noticed that subprocess creates a child process and nohup is not keeping it alive. It needs to work both on Windows and Linux, so I'm not sure if os.fork will work.

The structure I am aiming for is a main program running at all times that calls other programs, and if the main program dies I want the spawned programs to live on.

Main program

```
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python", "/home/jchoinski/Desktop/Sentinel1.1/programTest.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
   time.sleep(1)
```

Spawned Program

```
import time

l = 1
while l < 100000:
    l += 1
    print(l)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The process tree looks like this:

MainProgram
|_CalledProgram

and I want it to look like:

MainProgram
CalledProgram

Any ideas? Should I even use subprocess for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947711/call-a-python-subprocess-as-daemon-and-exit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592219/launch-a-totally-independent-process-from-python?rq=1

Comment: The first link does not spawn an independent process and the second link does not work for *nix systems.

Comment: Not sure how to do it platform independent, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client have some general clues.

Comment: don't use `PIPE` unless you read from the pipes. [Use `subprocess.DEVNULL` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279). Also, use `close_fds=True` explicitly (Python 2 requires it). It should also fix "nohup is not keeping it alive" issue.

Comment: I've managed to get the program to keep running on *nix system with nohup, but that option is not available for Windows. I guess I'll just have to check for os type and handle the cases accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a true universal way to start the program independently as it's own process. I managed to get what I want by checking to see if it is a *nix OS and appending 'nohup' to the beginning if true. Windows does not kill child processes so it worked out.

Comment: [`nohup` is not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6011235/4279), you might need `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` too (and perhaps [other points from Unix daemon list](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)). There are no process trees on Windows. There are  "Job Objects" on Windows and [the default behavior is not to kill child processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/53208/4279)

Comment: here's [code example that shows how to emulate `nohup` in pure Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27549535/4279)

Answer (score -1):

Use [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library instead and run the process as `daemon`.

Comment: it is the opposite of what OP wants. If the main process exits then all its  daemonic child processes are killed. Note: [daemon process in `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) has a _different_ meaning from [Unix daemon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)