# Run subprocess command in parallel

Tags: python, xml, matlab

is there a way that I could modify the below code to execute the matlab field solver command in the subprocess line in parallel?

The below code parses an xml file and creates 8000 copies of it with different filenames and changes in the parameters as per the for loops and then calls the matlab field solver to solve each one of them sequentially.

Running them sequentially is time consuming and just tedious, so I was wondering if there is a way I could modify this such that it opens 4-5 terminals and runs 4-5 xml files in parallel? It would really reduce the time to run all these files.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import subprocess
import os
def frange(start, end, step):
    tmp = start
    while(tmp <= end):
        yield tmp
        tmp += step

#print os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC')
#print os.getcwd()
fileCount = 1
tree = ET.parse('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\IMLC_v4p8_Aravind.xml')
#tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
root = tree.getroot()
#print(root.attrib)
#    print child.tag, child.attrib
#import py2exe

#print root[3].attrib
for child in root.iter('Traces'):
    child.find('TS')
    child.find('TW')
    for i in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
        child.set('TS',str(i))
        for k in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
                child.set('TW',str(i))
                for child2 in root.iter('Stackup'):
                    child2.find('core_h')
                    for j in frange(2,4,0.5):
                        for child3 in root.iter('Definition'):
                            child3.set('modelname', 'Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
                        child2.set('core_h',str(j))
                        tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
                        subprocess.call(['imlc.exe','C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount)],shell=True)
                        fileCount = fileCount+1

       # for j in frange(2,4,0.5):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use python threading with a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). You put the XML file names into the queue and have a pool of (5?) threads executing the subprocess.call you want. This gives you full control.

Other solution you could consider subprocess.Popen as per answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947711/call-a-python-subprocess-as-daemon-and-exit). But I think that gives you less control over the amount of subprocesses being called. It will just 'fire and forget'.

Comment: I think using threads would be better than Popen. Thanks for the answer!